# Is there a way to kill a range of session ids (connections) in ms sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql

i was wondering if there is a way to kill a range of SQL Connections on an Microsoft SQL DB.

If i want to kill a single session id i can use `kill [session-id]; go;`.

If i want to kill all sessions i can switch the db mode with `ALTER DATABASE [DB-NAME] SET SINGLE_USER WITHROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`

But what if i want to kill session id range 60-100 for example, or all sessions from a specific Hostname or a specific username? Is there a simple way for this? I didn't found a solution with the "kill" command. Any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing built in to do what you're asking. The easiest way would be to write a query to script it for you, then copy/paste and execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't actually execute this myself.  ;)  However.

```
Declare @procid int,
        @SQL nvarchar(max)


SET @procid=60
WHILE @procid < 100
BEGIN
    set @SQL='kill ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,@procid)
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
    SET @procid=@procid+1
END
```

As for processes from a specific hostname or username:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        SPID INT,
        Status VARCHAR(MAX),
        LOGIN VARCHAR(MAX),
        HostName VARCHAR(MAX),
        BlkBy VARCHAR(MAX),
        DBName VARCHAR(MAX),
        Command VARCHAR(MAX),
        CPUTime INT,
        DiskIO INT,
        LastBatch VARCHAR(MAX),
        ProgramName VARCHAR(MAX),
        SPID_1 INT,
        REQUESTID INT
)

Declare @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @spid int

INSERT INTO @Table EXEC sp_who2

SELECT  @spid = min(SPID) FROM @Table WHERE HostName/Login = 'Whatever'

while @spid is not null

BEGIN
    set @SQL='kill ' + convert(nvarchar,@spid)
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
    SELECT  @spid = min(SPID) FROM @Table WHERE HostName/Login = 'Whatever' and spid > @spid            
END
```

(Obviously, you'd have these scripts lying around beforehand.)